# Does Local Server Admin Become Domain Admin When New Domain Is Created?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

Does the local server administrator become a domain administrator when new a domain is created on that server?

This question relates to a 2008 server.

Whenever I login through Logmein I am logging in to this in the **log on to** field: DOMAINNAME (This Computer). However, the server's hostname is Projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed true. When you do a DCPromo/ADDS Setup and create a new Domain, the local Administrator gets promoted to Domain Administrator, and the local user database is inactive.